# PHP: Radiobutton will direct to another page without using a button/submit

Tags: php, html

**Scenario:**

I have a radio button where when the user click the radio button it will redirect to another page....

So here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldNetname FROM tbldata WHERE fldMonth = '$get_month' AND fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldNetname ORDER BY fldNetname");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio)){
echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldNetname']."' " .($_POST['playRadio'] == $row['fldNetname'] ? 'checked' : '') . " onClick=\'this.form.action='looptime_utilization_process.php'; this.form.submit()\' >";
    echo $row['fldNetname'];"</div>";
}
    ?>
```

When I try to run it there is no error yet its not directing to the page I want.
IS there a way that the radio button will be also like a button that can be proceed to another form?

Thanks.

Comment: try changing the \' around the onclick javascript to \"

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected all your HTML and PHP mistakes:

```
<?php
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldNetname FROM tbldata WHERE fldMonth = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($get_month) . "' AND fldWeek = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($get_week) . "' GROUP BY fldNetname ORDER BY fldNetname");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio)) {
?>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="playRadio" class="chk_boxes1" value="<?php echo $row['fldNetname']; ?>"<?php echo ($_POST['playRadio'] == $row['fldNetname'] ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''); ?> onclick="this.form.action='looptime_utilization_process.php'; this.form.submit();">
  <?php echo $row['fldNetname']; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

What I changed:

1. added `mysql_real_escape_string();` - better security if your variables are not already escaped
2. change echo string concatening to close / open `<?php` tags
3. changed `onClick` to `onclick` (all attributes should be written in lower case in most modern standarts)
4. changed `checked` to `checked="checked"`
5. corrected wrong quotes in `onclick` attribute

Comment: @DanFromGermany..hey! sorry for late reply..thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='looptime_utilization_process.php'>
<input type='radio' name='playRadio' class='chk_boxes1' onClick='form.submit();' >
<form>
```

Comment: @GaryHayes.... It is okay if there is a two <form>??? like... <form> <form><input type="radio"></form></form>

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: He put in `<form>` because there is none in your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript

```
if(document.getElementsByID("playradio").value==<ur value>)
{
param="<ur parameters>";
xmlhttp.open("GET", "looptime_utilization_process.php?".param ,false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: @RameshYadav...in this code "value==<ur value>)" what do you mean my value?

Comment: parameter you want to pass to another page ... learn more about ajax to use ...  if you don't have any parameter don't add

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$trgt=$_POST['playRadio'];
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldNetname FROM tbldata WHERE fldMonth = '$get_month' AND fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldNetname ORDER BY fldNetname");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio)){
 $v=$row['fldNetname'];
 echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio' class='chk_boxes1' value='$v'" 
    .($trgt == $v ? 'checked' : '')
    .' onclick="o=document.forms[0];o.action=\'looptime_utilization_process.php\'; o.submit()" >';
 echo "$v</div>";
}
```

You had some issues with the quotes in your `onClick` section. Also `this` does not work there in the way you wanted. I replaced it by `document.forms[0]`, assuming that it is the first `form` on that page you want to submit and of course, also assuming that the radio buttons *are* actually inside `<form>` tags! Change this as required ...

And, of course: placing the `action=...` context in the `onclick` section of the radio buttons really only makes sense if the original action of the form pointed to something else which needs to be there for other use cases. Otherwise follow  Gary Hayes' advice and put the action attribute into the `<form>...</form>` tags.